# Algorithms for finding closest vector

Tags: algorithm, vector, cluster-analysis

I have a set of vectors. For a vector in that set I like to find the sub set that is closeest to this vector. What algorithm can do this.

Comment: Do your vectors represent "points" or "directions"? I ask because the cosine distance measure mentioned in some answers will normalize the magnitude, which may not be what you want if you're looking for a Euclidean (or other Minkowski-norm) distance. If that's the case, you want a conventional nearest-neighbor algorithm kd-trees, k-means clustering, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

This class of algorithms is called *Nearest Neighbor* or *K Nearest Neighbor*.

The [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) as excepeiont says will work if direction of vector is important. If the vector represents a position in a space, then any metric for representing a distance in the space will work.

For example the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_metric): take the square root of the sum of squares difference in each dimension. This will give you a distance for each vector, then sort your set of vectors ascending on this distance.

This process will be O(N) in time. If this is too slow for you, you might want to look at some common [K Nearest Neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

use the cosinus similarity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) among the vectors and then sort them.

Comment: +1 I was going to mention the scalar product only. I didn't think about the vector lengths. Thanks for saving me from ridicule ;)

Comment: we don't know what he wants as distance

Answer (score 2):

If your problem relates to large amount of data:

I published a related algorithm on ddj.com, that finds the nearest line to a given *point*:

[Accelerated Search For the Nearest Line](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/198900559)

You would have to modify this algorithm by i.e. by converting the given vector to a number of points. This will reduce the number of *possible* matches drastically. The exact match has then to be checked for each possible match by

- Find the cutting point of both vectors or
- Get distance from vector start and end point to the possible match, as described in the article